# problema con bracket en el css

Tags: brackets

Hola tengo un problema en la vista previa de brackets trato de ver los cambios en el preview. 
Cuando edito el css quiero ver los cambios en directo, eso pasa. Pero cuando le doy a cargar en el botón del rayo me carga un archivo antiguo, no el que estoy trabajando o hice el cambio.
Que puedo hacer?
Como reparar eso?

Comment: falta más información para ponernos en contexto ¿Cuál botón del rayo?

Comment: Se refiere a este IDE [brackets](http://brackets.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Me paso lo mismo, no puede encontrar una solución, lo que yo hice fue **reinstalar** brackets y se solucionaba temporalmente, pero al poco tiempo volvia a presentar el mismo problema, como si se llenara el cache de nuevo, intente borrar algunos archivos a mano, pero me cargue el IDE.